# jquery - getting all parameters passed instead of just one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The code below calls two functions when a pop up on my site loads. They are `function callA` and `function callB`. Both functions rely on getting the `id` to work. I am struggling to pass the `id` properly to `function b`. In `function a`  this works great since it the getting of the `id` is inside the `jQuery.each function`.

However I need to have the `id` available outside of the `.each` so it can pass to `callB`. The way I had tried to do this was `var r_id = jQuery(html).attr("id");` but as I suspected, it only gets a single `id` at a time. How do I get multiple `ids` and have them passed so that this works properly?

```
 jQuery(document).on('popup/show', (event, popup_id) => {
      if (popup_id === 123) {
        function callA() {
          jQuery.ajax({
            data: {
              action: 'list_count'
            },
            type: 'post',
            url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
              var id = jQuery().data('id')
              var html = '';
    
              jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                html += '<div class="accordion-header ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" id="' + value.id + '" style="display:table-row">';
                html += '<div class="image"  style="display: table-cell";>' + value.img + '</div>';
                html += '<div style="display: table-cell";>' + value.Name + '</div>';
                html += '<div  style="display: table-cell">' + value.Size + '</div>';
                html += '<div  style="display: table-cell"> ' + value.Number + ' </div>';
                html += '<div class="tdid_' + value.id + '"  style="display: table-cell">' + value.Status + '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div id="cid_' + value.id + '" class="bg_clear ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: table-cell">';
                html += '<div class="bg_clear ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: table-cell"></div>';
                html += '  </div>';
              });
              jQuery('#list').html(html);
              var r_id = jQuery(html).attr("id"); //<<<<<<<<<<<<< gets the id from the .each and passes it 
              callB(r_id);
            }
          });
        }
    
        function callB(r_id) {
          jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
            data: {
              action: 'options_function',
              cid: r_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
              jQuery(data).insertAfter('#cid_' + r_id)
              console.log(data);
              console.log('#cid_' + r_id);
            }
          });
        }
    
        callA();
      }
    });
```

Comment: SO make a list of the ids, loop over them.

Comment: I had done that but then it outputs them as all together - like ids = 744679 instead of 74, 46, 79. Also the ids, arent static, they are dynamic

Comment: You are building a string, not pushing to an array

Comment: ok, then what does the solution look like because I am not sure how to make that happen and have it properly link up with the divs' from the each? Possible to post an example or direct me to some article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `.each()` loop, you can gather the ids in an array:

```
let id_array = [];

jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
  
  id_array.push(value.id); // Add ids with this
  
  // A couple lines of those... That is the rest of your actual loop
  //html += ...
  
});
jQuery('#list').html(html);

callB(id_array);  // <== Pass the array of ids
```

Comment: Ah I se thank you. So basically I am running two `.each` inside `function callA`?

Comment: No! using the same `.each()`, you can fill the array.

Comment: Thanks so much.So the issue I am experiencing is that it is outputting like this - Array [ "46", "47" ] instead of being able to link to each div as it runs through the loop. Seems to be taking exception to the word "array" being put infront of each result

Comment: If you want to make the `callB` for every `id`... Then just do `callB(value.id);` inside the `each()` loop! No need for the array.

Comment: Understood. so `id_array.push(value.id);` in the `.each`' loop changes to `callB(value.id);`? Tried that but it tells me 'callB' isnt a function, which makes sense.

Comment: I feel like you should read about what in an aŕray.

Comment: Thanks. I did both read and trying literally placing `CallB() into the `each` loop but it gives me the error above.
The first time it gave me an error since I didnt know I needed to remove the `callB(value.id)` from below the loop code. Now that I have commented this out, this works. Thanks much